# Convert rows to columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, pivot, unpivot

I have a SQL Server table with following data

```
SKU || Value || Volume 
 AB      2        3
 AB      2        2
 BB      1        3
```

Expected output :

```
AB(value) || BB (VALUE) || AB(Volume) || BB (Volume)     
   4             1              5           3
```

Note: `Sku` column data will be dynamic

Thanks

Comment: You need to use a PIVOT. However the column you will be pivoting on is dynamic, so I suspect this will be incredibly difficult to do programmaticly

Comment: BY taking pivoted column values into one variable and then we can pass that variable to Pivot 'Select  '+@cols+' From test
                      
              
            PIVOT
            (
              SUM([value]) FOR  [SKU] IN ('+@cols+') 
                           
            ) P   
            '

Answer (score 3):

You can use the PIVOT function to get the result. Since you are going to have an unknown number of `SKU` values, I would first write a hard-coded version of the query then convert it to dynamic SQL.

Since you have two columns that you want to pivot data from `value` and `volume`, then I would first unpivot those two columns into multiple rows and then apply the PIVOT function.  The unpivot syntax can use the UNPIVOT function or CROSS APPLY:

```
select col = t.sku+'_'+ c.col, 
  c.val
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  select 'value', value union all
  select 'volume', volume
) c (col, val)
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/150a0/8). This gives a result:

```
|       COL | VAL |
|  AB_value |   2 |
| AB_volume |   3 |
|  AB_value |   2 |
| AB_volume |   2 |
|  BB_value |   1 |
| BB_volume |   3 |
```

Once you have the data into a format that is similar to this, then you can apply the PIVOT:

```
select AB_Value, BB_Value, AB_Volume, BB_Volume
from
(
  select col = t.sku+'_'+ c.col, 
    c.val
  from yourtable t
  cross apply
  (
    select 'value', value union all
    select 'volume', volume
  ) c (col, val)
) d
pivot
(
  sum(val)
  for col in (AB_Value, BB_Value, AB_Volume, BB_Volume)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/150a0/9).  Now since you will have an unknown number of values, then you will have to use dynamic SQL to generate the SQL string that you need to execute:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(sku+'_'+col) 
                    from yourtable
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'value', 1 union all
                      select 'volume', 2
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by sku, so, col
                    order by so, sku
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select col = t.sku+''_''+ c.col, 
                c.val
              from yourtable t
              cross apply
              (
                select ''value'', value union all
                select ''volume'', volume
              ) c (col, val)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(val)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/150a0/10).  Both versions give a result:

```
| AB_VALUE | BB_VALUE | AB_VOLUME | BB_VOLUME |
|        4 |        1 |         5 |         3 |
```

Comment: W00t W00t! Answering pivot questions is a lot more fun than a beach.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ebcc/29)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([SKU] varchar(2), [Value] int, [Volume] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([SKU], [Value], [Volume])
VALUES
    ('AB', 2, 3),
    ('AB', 2, 2),
    ('BB', 1, 3)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @colTable table(rownum int,columnName varchar(20),value int,volume int)
INSERT INTO @colTable SELECT row_number() over (ORDER BY SKU), SKU, 
                             SUM(Value), SUM(Volume) FROM Table1 GROUP BY SKU
DECLARE @query varchar(500)
DECLARE @i int, @max int
SET @i = 1
SET @max = (SELECT count(*) FROM @colTable)
SET @query = 'select '
WHILE @i <= @max
BEGIN
    IF @i > 1 SET @query = @query + ','
    SET @query = @query + 
             (SELECT cast(value as varchar) FROM @colTable WHERE rownum = @i) + 
             ' AS "' + 
             (SELECT columnName FROM @colTable WHERE rownum = @i) + '(Value)"'
    SET @query = @query + ','
    SET @query = @query + 
             (SELECT cast(volume as varchar) FROM @colTable WHERE rownum = @i) + 
             ' AS "' + 
             (SELECT columnName FROM @colTable WHERE rownum = @i) + '(Volume)"'
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
exec(@query)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ebcc/29/0)**:

```
| AB(VALUE) | AB(VOLUME) | BB(VALUE) | BB(VOLUME) |
|-----------|------------|-----------|------------|
|         4 |          5 |         1 |          3 |
```